# How to include only some items of internal list with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have following entities (simplified for readability):

```
public class Country
{
    public List<NameLocalized> Names;
}

public class NameLocalized
{
    public string Locale;
    public string Value;
}
```

I also have a `DbSet<Country> Countries` in my context. How to write a LINQ query which will return the list of countries but with filtered Names (so `Names` list will contain only single item based on specified locale. Something like this (however, this is not a working example)

```
public List<Country> GetCountries(string locale)
{
    var result = context.Countries.Include(c => c.Names.Select(n => n.Locale == locale)).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

How to achieve this in 2 steps if not possible in one

```
public List<Country> GetCountries(string locale)
{
    //I have to use Include for eager loading
    var tempResult = context.Countries.Include(c => c.Names);

    var result = //Some code to convert tempResult to result, where only interesting locale is included
    return result;
}
```

I am trying following code to remove unnecessary items, but it does not work too

```
result.ForEach(c => c.Names.ToList().RemoveAll(n => n.Locale != locale));
```

UPDATE:
I have managed to remove items with following code (using extension method)

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this ICollection<T> collection,Predicate<T> predicate) 
{
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
    }
     collection.Where(entity => predicate(entity))
        .ToList().ForEach(entity => collection.Remove(entity));
}


result.ForEach(c => c.Names.RemoveAll(n => n.Locale != locale));
```

UPDATE2:

With the help of answers and comments I was able to succeed. Details are at [Convert Entity with navigation property to DTO using IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343067/convert-entity-with-navigation-property-to-dto-using-iqueryable)

Comment: It's all (`Include`) or nothing. No third option.

Comment: See [this useful library](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters).

Comment: Be aware that if you remove entities *and then save the context* then you'll end up removing those relationships in your database. I would seriously warn against the approach you've come up with, as it's likely to cause you pain in the future.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I have to agree

Answer (score 1):

Since your model defines `Country` as something that has multiple `Names`, it may be confusing to have a `Country` instance that only has one of its `Names`. Instead, create a separate type to represent the concept of the information that is known about a `Country` for a given locale.

```
public class LocaleCountry
{
    public int CountryId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Locale {get;set;}
}


public List<LocaleCountry> GetCountries(string locale)
{
    var result = context.Countries
        .Select(c => new LocaleCountry
        {
            CountryId = c.Id,
            Name = c.Names
               .Where(n => n.Locale == locale)
               .Select(n => n.Name)),
            Locale = locale
        })
        .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I doing after I query database. (did not include this part for brevity). I am just not quite happy manually creating new objects (my DTO is automatically generated by some VS extension)

Comment: @Ingweland: Well, as far as I can tell, this is still the best approach. It allows Entity Framework to only get out exactly the information that it needs from the database in a single round-trip. Can you explain why you don't want to "create new objects?" If there's a legitimate reason not to map to the generated DTO, then create a separate one.

Comment: The main reason why I want to avoid manual creation is that it's easy to forget to update such places later in case entity's structure is changed. Plus, in my real project, the entity is quite complex. Maybe it's better to create some proxy object, which will hold Country (but without Names at all) and concrete Name as separate property. Then, to feed EntityToDto converter with this proxy object. What do you think?

Comment: @Ingweland: You've identified a class that you want to be solely responsible for converting Entities to DTOs, right? It would work okay to feed it the countries and names separately, but it may be simpler to *either* make that class provide an `Expression<Func<Country, CountryNameDto>>` which other classes could throw into a `.Select()` off of a list of countries, *or* make that class's function apply its transformation to a given `IQueryable<Country>` parameter, so you can still get the advantages of deferred execution while applying the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: It would be awesome if you can provide some code example describing your suggestions. I am still learning c# and not sure how to implement them into workable solution.

Comment: I found following info about AutoMapper and its Queryable Extensions https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions It looks interesting. However, I was not able to make it work in my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322110/system-nullreferenceexception-when-using-automappers-queryable-extensions

Comment: As I understand, IQueryable solution will not fit if I have navigation properties inside my entity which in turn should be converted to corresponding DTOs. Suppose I have ToDto extension methods, but they could not be called in case of IQueryable.

Comment: @Ingweland: That would certainly complicate things a bit. If you use the Expression-based approach then you could use LINQKit to "expand" the LINQ Expression.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I succeeded finally. Updated my question and included the link to solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Country> GetCountries(string locale)
{
    var result = context.Countries.Select(c => new Country { Names = c.Names.Select(n => n.Locale == locale).ToList() }).ToList();
    return result;
}

public List<Country> GetCountries(string locale)
{
    var result = context.Countries.Where(c => c.Names.Any(n => n.Locale == locale)).ToList();
    result.ForEach(c => c.Names = c.Names.Where(n => n.Locale == locale).ToList());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way? I have a lot of properties in my real Entity type, and I would like to avoid creating anonymous objects where I have to map all those properties.

Comment: No, I will add another way

Comment: the problem, is the second method load the entire table in memory

Comment: the second method does not work - produces compile time error

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert IEnumarable<bool> to ICollection<Country> - this is on the line with ForEach

Comment: See I have changed the Select to a Where

Comment: Runtime error now (I am using Entity framework if it matters) The property 'Names' on type 'Country_A2C86D7830BF428A8404AF27F1C6E2B219516FF911669D22B6C16122CA4AAE7A' cannot be set because the collection is already set to an EntityCollection.

Comment: It looks like the classes returned from entity framework are proxies with change tracking enabled. I am thinking it might be better for you to put this Names filtering logic somewhere other than where you load the entities. So, get rid of the ForEach and return all Names and then let your application pick out the correct name instance later on.