# Convert Entity with navigation property to DTO using IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

Suppose I have following entities and dtos

```
public class Country
{
    public List<NameLocalized> NamesLocalized;
    public CountryData Data;
}

public class NameLocalized
{
    public string Locale;
    public string Value;
}

public class CountryData
{
    public int Population;
}

public class CountryDto
{
    public String Name;
    public CountryDataDto Data;
}

public class CountryDataDto
{
    public int Population;
}
```

I need to convert Country to CountryDto (and ideally, I want to make a single query to the database). I have received few suggestions in my other questions on Stackoverflow, and can now accomplish the task, but only partially. I am stuck at how to convert navigation property (`CountryData` in this case). I was suggested to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for this, but have no idea how to implement it. Here is my code which populates only `Name` property but not `Data` navigation property.

```
public static async Task<List<CountryDto>> ToDtosAsync(this IQueryable<Country> source, string locale)
{
    if(source == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var result = await source
        .Select(src => new CountryDto
        {    
           Name = src.NamesLocalized.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Locale == locale).Name
        })
        .ToListAsync();

    return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27550872/3507404) answer gave me the hint for my solution. You need to use LINQKit and build Expression to convert the navigation property.

```
public static Expression<Func<CountryData, CountryDataDto>> ConverterExpression = cd => new CountryDataDto
        {
            Population = cd.Population
        };

public static async Task<List<CountryDto>> ToDtosAsync(this IQueryable<Country> source, string locale)
{
    if(source == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var result = await source
        .AsExpandable
        .Select(src => new CountryDto
        {    
           Name = src.NamesLocalized.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Locale == locale).Name
           Data = ConverterExpression.Invoke(src.Data)
        })
        .ToListAsync();

    return result; 
}
```